# How to use CASE WHEN expression in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize ORM for Node.js, how do you use CASE/WHEN expression in a select statement?

I do not see any reference or examples to use the SQL expression [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) according to [Sequelize Documentation](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/) .  Is this possible?

Here's my example:

**SQL**

```
SELECT userId, Status, 
  MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'Employee' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END) AS "Employee",
  MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'School' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END) AS "School",
  MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'Public' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END) AS "Public",
  MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'Other' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END) AS "Other"
FROM Database.dbo.invoice
WHERE Status IN ('Included', 'Excluded')
GROUP BY userId,  Status
```

**Sequelize**

```
var query = {
  attributes: ['userId'], // need to include Rate (as Employee, School, Public, Other for each CASE/WHEN)
  /*
    MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'Employee' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END) AS "Employee",
    MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'School' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END) AS "School",
    MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'Public' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END) AS "Public",
    MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'Other' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END) AS "Other"
*/
  where: {
    user: userId,
    Type: ['Employee', 'School', 'Public', 'Other'],
  },
  group: ['userId'],
  raw: true
};
models.invoice.findAll(query).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

**Database Structure**

```
+--------+------+----------+
| userId | Rate | Type     |
+--------+------+----------+
| 1      | 2.00 | Employee |
+--------+------+----------+
| 1      | 3.50 | School   |
+--------+------+----------+
| 1      | 4.00 | Public   |
+--------+------+----------+
| 1      | 2.50 | Other    |
+--------+------+----------+
| 2      | 3.75 | Employee |
+--------+------+----------+
| 2      | 4.25 | School   |
+--------+------+----------+
| 2      | 2.00 | Public   |
+--------+------+----------+
| 2      | 3.00 | Other    |
+--------+------+----------+
```

**Desired Result:**

```
+--------+----------+--------+--------+-------+
| userId | Employee | School | Public | Other |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+-------+
| 1      | 2.00     | 3.50   | 4.00   | 2.50  |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+-------+
| 2      | 3.75     | 4.25   | 2.00   | 3.00  |
+--------+----------+--------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what Type: ['Employee', 'School', 'Public', 'Other'] means ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [Sequelize.literal](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-literal) in `attributes` to build special queries

```
var query = {
  attributes: [
    'userId',
    [Sequelize.literal(`MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'Employee' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END)`), 'Employee'],
    [Sequelize.literal(`MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'School' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END)`), 'School'],
    [Sequelize.literal(`MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'Public' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END)`), 'Public'],
    [Sequelize.literal(`MAX(CASE Type WHEN 'Other' THEN Rate ELSE 0 END)`), 'Other'],
  ],
  where: {
    user: userId,
    Type: ['Employee', 'School', 'Public', 'Other'],
  },
  group: ['userId'],
  raw: true
};
models.invoice.findAll(query).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```