# Sequelize Subtraction of counts

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I am trying to get the count by subtracting all records that have false from all the records that have true. I am unable to replicate such a thing in Sequelize but I was able to create it in a raw query:

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(id) 
    FROM   votes 
    WHERE  up = true 
           AND id = 1) - (SELECT Count(id) 
                                   FROM   votes 
                                   WHERE  up = false 
                                          AND id = 1) AS votes
```

Based off the documentation, I do not see a way to do such a thing. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: a `case expression` would make this simpler, and I imagine therefore easier in your js library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be simpler for your js lib to handle

```
select count(case when up = true then 1 end) - count(case when up = false then 1 end)
from votes
where id = 1
```

then this previous answer should help I think:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47397320/2067753

Note that the `count()` function ignores nulls, but using `sum()` instead of count can give the same end result:

```
select sum(case when up = true then 1 else 0 end) - sum(case when up = false then 1 else 0 end)
from votes
where id = 1
```

using `group by`:

```
select id, count(case when up = true then 1 end) - count(case when up = false then 1 end)
from votes
where id = 1
group by id
```