# How to use COUNT DISTINCT CASE expression in Sequelize ORM mapping to MySQL database?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am new to Sequelize and trying to write equivalent Sequelize query in Node js for the following MySQL select statement.

```html
SELECT date(Game.TournamentDate) Date,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Game in('Ludo','Cricket') && (Player.Status in ('Active','Rest')) THEN Point END) Field1 ,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Player.Code in('PLY1','PLY2') && (Player.Status = 'Sleeping') THEN Point END) Field2  
FROM Game 
       LEFT JOIN Player ON Game.ID = Player.ID 
WHERE Game.TournamentDate BETWEEN '" + dateFrom + "' AND DATE_ADD('" + dateTo + "',INTERVAL 1 day) 
GROUP BY date(Game.TournamentDate) 
ORDER BY date(Game.TournamentDate)
```

** Query is altered for demo purpose.

I have seen this question [How to use CASE WHEN expression in Sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396796/how-to-use-case-when-expression-in-sequelize?rq=1) but I want to know the feature close to Sequelize, but in case if there is no easy or possible way to do it in native syntax then please let me know the meaning of following syntax in where condition of the question mentioned in the link.

```
Type: ['Employee', 'School', 'Public', 'Other']
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can go for Raw Query as well in sequilize. Something like this

```
sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(users => {})
```

[Check Out this](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html)