# Convert CASE statements to Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, aggregate-functions

I have ticketing system with ticket status. I want to do sequelize query which will return respective status counts. Below is the raw query which is working fine, I want to convert it into sequelize.

```
let querydata = `SELECT count(*) as total,
sum(case when status = 'Allocated' then 1 else 0 end) as allocated,
sum(case when status = 'RemindMe' then 1 else 0 end) as remindme,
sum(case when status = 'Close' then 1 else 0 end) as closed
FROM ticketnotifications
WHERE createdby = '` + req.auth.credentials.email + `';`;
return ticketdb.sequelize.query(querydata, { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
  .then((agentCountResult) => {
    return res(agentCountResult[0]);
  }).catch((err) => {
    logger.error('agentCount exception...', err);
    return res(boom.expectationFailed(err));
  });
```

I tried `[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('id')), 'total']` and its working but I'm stucked around that how to convert above `Case` statement in sequelize. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use CASE WHEN expression in Sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396796/how-to-use-case-when-expression-in-sequelize)